# Ubuntu Desktop folders, icons, and files are not visible

Tags: desktop-environments

I am using ubuntu 16.10. When I create any folder in the desktop the icon is invisible. I know the folder has been created because it is visible in nautilus or from the terminal. Same issue when trying to copy icons or files to the desktop. My desktop is just blank.

I tried tweak tool>Desktop Icons. It is ON.

Comment: I would like to add on that when I try to run nautilus in terminal i get the following error :(nautilus:4303): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:4303): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login screen combo Ctrl + Alt + F1 enter username and password then run the following commands:

`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

`DISPLAY=:0 dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

`unity --reset-icons`

`setsid unity`

and finally reboot

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked. 
I realize the problem now, I enabled Wallpaper in CCSM, to have multiple backgrounds for different workspaces. 
After doing some search I realize it's either icons on desktop, or workspace wallpapers.
Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is to open the Desktop in Nautilus and just select everything in there and drag it out onto my actual Desktop. After this, the files shown under Desktop in Nautilus and those visible on your Desktop are in sync again and all actions are applied to both of them.

Comment: opening a file manager did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. I found the reason to be the modification of the positions of the screens (in the parameters). It seems the system keep the old position and display files in wrong places (where there is no Desktop).

I finally restore the original position of the screens as they were at first to avoid this issue (sorry about this non-solution, but it still can help!).